anylogic is it possible to have trucks at population location
I'm new to AnyLogic. The problem is I have 13 distributors and 38 retailers (both distributors and retailers are population agents, loaded with addresses using GIS location names). I want to add trucks that will deliver goods from the distributors to the retailers. Is it possible? Please teach me how to add the trucks at the distributors and make them send goods to the retailers. Thanks!

Welcome to SOF. This place works best for you if you ask very focused, specific questions on 1 AnyLogic issue, show exactly what you tried already and where you are stuck. If you want to know “how do I best do X in AnyLogic”, you should use the LinkedIn forum instead. Check this overview to the community to understand why: https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-community. Else, try to break down your broad question into specific sub-questions and ask them separately, see https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-stackoverflow. Welcome again, happy to help
